# Passing variable params to another variable params

Tags: c#

I want to pass a `params` object from my method to another methods `params` object like the following, but I cannot figure out the syntax, or if it is even possible.

```
readonly ILogger<T> _logger;
readonly string _businessUnit = "Marketing";

private void LogTheThing(string message, params object?[] args) {
  _logger.LogInformation($"{{BusinessUnit}} - {message}", _businessUnit, args);
}

public void Go() {
  LogTheThing($"{{OrderId}} - Could not locate your order. Try searching for {{ExternalOrderId}}", 45623, "A987BZ1");
}
```

Currently when I pass `LogTheThing`'s `args` to the `ILogger`'s `args`, the array of objects from my method winds up in the first array element of the `Ilogger`'s `args`.

I tried these with no luck:

```
_logger.LogInformation($"{{BusinessUnit}} - {message}", _businessUnit, args.ToArray()); // nope
_logger.LogInformation($"{{BusinessUnit}} - {message}", _businessUnit, args.ToList()); // nope
```

This [example](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/params#example) actually shows the unwanted - default behavior.

---

Is it possible to "spread" my `args` and have c# treat it as:

```
_logger.LogInformation($"{{BusinessUnit}} - {message}", _businessUnit, args[0], args[1], arg[x]...);
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [C# - pass on expanded params array to another function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62859826/c-sharp-pass-on-expanded-params-array-to-another-function)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically you'd need to create an array containing both `_businessUnit` *and* all the `args` contents:

```cs
object[] newArgs = new object[args.Length + 1];
newArgs[0] = _businessUnit;
Array.Copy(args, 0, newArgs, 1, args.Length);
_logger.LogInformation($"{{BusinessUnit}} - {message}", newArgs);
```

There's nothing built into C# as a *language* to do that.

Answer (score 1):

This code doesn't solve your problem, but it might give you a different approach.

```
using (logger.BeginScope("{{BusinessUnit}}", _businessUnit))
{
   logger.LogInformation(message, args);
}
```